# How to this fix for(object : List){}

Tags: java

Code:

```
 public List<InvoicePostAddressForm> invoicePostAddressListByStoreId(String storeId) throws BusinessException {
            List voList = new ArrayList();
            if (!result.getSuccess()) {  
                throw new BusinessException(result.getCode());
            }
            voList = (List)result.getResult();
            ArrayList<InvoicePostAddressForm> formList = new ArrayList<InvoicePostAddressForm>();
            for (InvoicePostAddressVo vo : voList) {  // here's error
                formList.add(this.ipavo2Form(vo));
            }
            return formList;
        }
```

Code is from a decompiled project, i dont have sorce code, and

```
for (InvoicePostAddressVo vo : voList)
```

show an error in editor , i use Idea

```
Incompatible types.

Required:Object

Found:InvoicePostAddressVo
```

InvoicePostAddressVo is a object, and it requires a object, why show this error?

Comment: Because you haven't specified the type of the list `List<InvoicePostAddressVo> voList = new ArrayList();`

Comment: As already mentioned, you should not use raw types. I.e. specify the generic type of a generic class **always**. So change `List` to `List<InvoicePostAddressVo>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why is this line:

```
List voList = new ArrayList();
```

Did you intend to do this, as opposed to something like this?

```
List<InvoicePostAddressVo> voList = new ArrayList<>();
```

When you try to iterate over the collection with the line

```
for (InvoicePostAddressVo vo : voList)
```

The compiler is expecting that voList guarantees all elements will be of type InvoicePostAddressVO, which is not the same as a list of Object.

You are strongly discouraged from using a raw List without good reason.